# Unpacking lists programmatically in R

Tags: r, list, apply

I am prototyping an application in R. I'm using the parallel library and parApply to run a function on columns of a data frame. I understand this will also be applicable to non-parallel/Apply application as well. I have a line similar to:

```
myBigList <- parApply(myCluster, myInputData, 2, myFunction)
```

where myFunction is a one that I have written, takes a vector as an input. The function itself performs quite a few operations that I can't go in to. It returns a list of variables of various classes. For the purposes of a MWE, say:

```
myFunction <- function(vectorIn){
    # CODE GOES HERE
    return(list(
        mean = mean(vectorIn),
        sd = mean(vectorIn),
        vectorOut = sumUserFunction(vectorIn),
        plot1 = aPlotGeneratingFunction(vectorIn),
    ))
```

What is returned to me is a list containing the results from the function. I can address elements from the list, eg:

```
myBigList$Column1$mean
```

But that isnt really helpful for my purposes. I'd like to know how to unpack the list so that I can look at all the mean values. eg:

```
listOfMeans <- myBigList$*ALL_ITEMS*$mean
```

so that listOfMeans is a vector with row.names, or data.frame with col.names.

Is this possible? I can think of a solution using a for loop but that doesnt seem very elegant.

I'd also like to do something similiar with the plots that I return so that I can automatically build a pdf containing all of them. I'm guessing learning the above will help.

tl;dr: What is the best methods of extracting common data names from a list?

EDIT: An actual MWE

```
library('ggplot2')

exampleData <- data.frame(Col1 = rnorm(100), Col2 = rnorm(100), Col3 = rnorm(100))

myFunction <- function(xIn){

  meanX <- mean(xIn)
  sdX <- sd(xIn)
  vecX <- xIn^2 + xIn

  plotX <- 
    ggplot(data.frame(xIn, vecX), aes(x = xIn, y = vecX)) +
    geom_point()

  return(list(
    mean = meanX,
    sd = sdX,
    vect = vecX,
    plot = plotX
  ))
}

myBigList <- apply(exampleData,
                   2,
                   myFunction)
```

Comment: Try `mymeans <- sapply(myBigList, \`[[\`, "mean")` where "mean" is the name of the element in each sublist that you want to extract

Comment: Thanks, 

For items in my list with single values this returns a vector with appropriate names. Exactly what I wanted.

For items in my list containign vectors, this return a list of vectors, again very acceptable.

But for items in the list containing plot handles (maybe not the correct term) it returns a matrix. I can't seem to figure out how to reporduce the plots from this.

Comment: That's why you should provide a minimal reproducible example. While you did show some code, it does not allow users to actually test/run it. For example, you could have shown a line like `x <- list(col1 = list(mean = 1, sd = 2),col2 = list(mean = 1, sd = 2),col3 = list(mean = 1, sd = 2) )` or one including plots and data.frames. Then, someone will tell you how to do it

Comment: good advice, i added a full example.

Comment: If you want to reprint the plots you can use `lapply(myBigList, \`[[\`, "plot")`. To create a data.frame of the "vect", it can be `as.data.frame(lapply(myBigList, \`[[\`, "vect"))`..

Comment: That work perfectly, thank you. I cant seen to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Comments cannot be accepted. Please write up an answer yourself showing how you solved the problem and then accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from @`docendo discusimus` comment

```
mymeans <- sapply(myBigList, '[[', 'mean')
```

returns a vector of all the values stores in mean. To return a list, which is useful for storing the plot class the command should be:

```
myplots <- lapply(myBigList, '[[', 'plot')
```